# How to print out a linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list

Can somebody help me fix this issue with the code that I wrote?

When I run it doesn't print out the values of the linked list. I don't understand what is the problem, the compiler keeps giving a blank screen when I run the code.

```
public class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    public static void main (String Args [])
    {
        Link object = new Link ();
        object.insert(15);
        object.insert(30);
        object.insert(50);
        object.insert(70);
        object.show();
    }
}


public class Link {

    Node head;

    void insert (int data)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data=data;

        if (head == null)
        {
            node=head;
        }

        else
        {
            Node n = head;
            while (n.next != null)
            {
                n=n.next;
            }
            n.next=node;
        }

    }

    void show ()
    {
        Node n = head;
        while (n != null)
        {
            System.out.println(n.data);
            n=n.next;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing this:

```
if (head == null)
{
    node=head;
}
```

This sets the null in `head` into the variable `node`. You aren't setting the value of `head`.

You should be doing this (setting the value of `node` into the variable `head`):

```
if (head == null)
{
    head = node;
}
```

Comment: @jcm If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

In your Link class, you need to change the following:

```
if (head == null)
{
    node=head; //<-- change this to   head = node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Do you have to do it by that way? Java has already a `LinkedList` utility, makes it easier.

Comment: Yes,  I am aware that there is a built in library, however since I am a beginner I figured I should know  how to build data structures from scratch.